# How to remove one datatable rows based on another datatable in .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datatable

I have one data table named `dtFirst` as shown below

```
Fieldname              Newvalue

antenastructure        12
slno                   2
servicelevel
powersupply
```

another data table as `dtMaster`

```
Mastertabe          Masterfield          infoid      zvalue     qvalue

M_seq               antenastructure       123          
M_seq               slno                  1      
M_seq               servicelevel          133
M_seq               powersupply           154
M_seq               azimheight            124
```

What i want is i want to remove rows from `dtMaster` if `Fieldname`   of   `dtFirst` doesn't contain  `Newvalue`    ie here i want to remove   rows contains `servicelevel` and  `powersupply`.These two are big data table out of which i am posting small part

Comment: C'mon, this is trivial - you should be able to code this up yourself - show us your efforts so far? Just do a Rows.Select on dtFirst to get the items without NewValues then iterate over dtMaster deleting rows without values in dtFirst.

Comment: i used the logic mentioned in link http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/686406/How-To-Compare-and-delete-datatable-row-using-Csha, but none of them made success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dtFirst = new DataTable();
            dtFirst.Columns.Add("Fieldname", typeof(string));
            dtFirst.Columns.Add("Newvalue", typeof(int));
            dtFirst.Columns["Newvalue"].AllowDBNull = true;

            dtFirst.Rows.Add(new object[] {"antenastructure", 12});
            dtFirst.Rows.Add(new object[] {"slno", 2});
            dtFirst.Rows.Add(new object[] {"servicelevel"});
            dtFirst.Rows.Add(new object[] {"powersupply"});

            string[] dtFirstValidRows = dtFirst.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int?>("Newvalue") != null).Select(x => x.Field<string>("Fieldname")).ToArray();

            DataTable dtMaster = new DataTable();
            dtMaster.Columns.Add("Mastertabe", typeof(string));
            dtMaster.Columns.Add("Masterfield", typeof(string));
            dtMaster.Columns.Add("infoid", typeof(int));
            dtMaster.Columns["infoid"].AllowDBNull = true;
            dtMaster.Columns.Add("zvalue", typeof(int));
            dtMaster.Columns["zvalue"].AllowDBNull = true;
            dtMaster.Columns.Add("qvalue", typeof(int));
            dtMaster.Columns["qvalue"].AllowDBNull = true;

            dtMaster.Rows.Add(new object[] {"M_seq", "antenastructure", 123});          
            dtMaster.Rows.Add(new object[] {"M_seq", "slno", 1});          
            dtMaster.Rows.Add(new object[] {"M_seq", "servicelevel", 133});          
            dtMaster.Rows.Add(new object[] {"M_seq", "powersupply", 154});          
            dtMaster.Rows.Add(new object[] {"M_seq", "azimheight", 124});

            dtMaster = dtMaster.AsEnumerable().Where(x => dtFirstValidRows.Contains(x.Field<string>("Masterfield"))).CopyToDataTable();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pseudo code typed on my phone:

```
var rowsWithoutVals = dtFirst.Rows.Select("newValues = ''");

for(int i = dtMaster.Rows.Count - 1; i > -1;i--) {

 foreach (var emptyItem in rowsWithoutVals) {
  if (emptyItem[0] == dtMaster[i][1]) {
    dtMaster.Rows.RemoveAt[i];
    break;
   }
 }
}
```